# How do I add a new screen with react-native-navigation (using pepperoni-starter-pack)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to prototype a mobile app using [pepperoni-app-kit](https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit), which uses [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). However I'm finding myself unable to add a new screen to the application; it's as if the screen just doesn't exist.

Here's how it uses `react-navigation`. I've added the `Pizza` screen.

```
import {TabNavigator, StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

export const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Pizza: {screen: PizzaLocator},
  Counter: {screen: CounterViewContainer},
  Color: {screen: ColorViewContainer},
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        activeTintColor: activeColor,
        indicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: activeColor},
        style: {backgroundColor: headerColor}
      }
    })
  }
})
```

For this new screen, I've imitated other screens in the starter pack:

```
class PizzaLocator extends Component {
  static displayName = "PizzaLocator"

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Pizza',
    tabBarLabel: "Pizza",
    tabBar: () => ({
      icon: (props) => (
        <Icon name='pizza' size={24} color="Yellow" />
      )
    }),
    // TODO: move this into global config?
    header: {
      tintColor: 'white',
      style: { backgroundColor: '#39babd' }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{"It's dangerous to go alone; take this map."}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I've also tried wrapping `PizzaLocator` in a trivial `PizzaLocatorContainer` (the most they do is `connect(Thing)`) as they do in the other screens, but it didn't change a thing.

What am I missing? Is the way Pepperoni uses `react-navigation` non-standard? Thanks!

Comment: you have tagged this question under [react-native-navigation] but you are using [react-navigation] - pls change

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal tool, cd to pepperoni's project, enter command: **yarn add react-navigation**, then do: **react-native run-ios**